# Is there a way to keep up with Facebook platform changes?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I notice Facebook makes changes every so often.  For example, it's html page structure changes every so often (if you write a like count scraper, then all of a sudden your scraper is broken one day).

Also I noticed URLs of the form https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=100000000000000 started redirecting to  https://www.facebook.com/{pagename}/videos/100000000000000 .... Probably the redirection will stay the same but I wonder - does Facebook publish these changes in behavior or how do you keep up with them?

I wasn't even sure this was the right place to post but I couldn't find a facebook stackoverflow community....Thanks!

Comment: Scraping is not allowed without written permission according which I assume you read https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php . So use the API

Answer (score 1):

If you build functionality off the Graph API there is a changelog, and versioning support e.g. you can build against a specific version and keep using functionality even though it is removed in later versions.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog